# MySQL row numbers for table

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to get row numbers for my table.
So far this is my SQL Prompt:

```
SELECT @i = @i + 1 AS Rank, x.Name, x.PartyName, x.ConstituencyName, x.Votes 
FROM (
    SELECT CONCAT(t1.Firstname, ' ', t1.Lastname) AS Name, t1.PartyName, t1.ConstituencyName, COALESCE(t2.Count, 0) AS Votes
        FROM (
            (SELECT db.user.PID, db.user.Firstname, db.user.Lastname, db.party.PartyName, db.constituency.ConstituencyName 
                FROM db.user
                LEFT JOIN db.party ON db.user.PartyId = db.party.PartyID 
                LEFT JOIN db.constituency ON db.user.CID = db.constituency.CID
                WHERE db.user.PartyId IS NOT NULL
                AND db.user.CID IS NOT NULL
            ) t1
            LEFT JOIN
            (SELECT db.user.Vote, COUNT(*) AS 'Count' 
                FROM db.user 
                GROUP BY db.user.Vote
            ) t2
        ON
            t1.PID = t2.Vote
        ORDER BY t2.Count DESC)
        ) x,
(SELECT @i:=1) r
```

So what this basically does is that, first I create a table t1(that gets information from 2 different tables) and then join it with table t2 so I can get every candidate with their total votes. Then I have marked that table as 'x' and joined it with the table 'r' that should initialise the row numbers(used an online tutorial for the row numbers). However when I run this SQL Prompt I get the following in return:

```
Rank    Name    PartyName   ConstituencyName    Votes
0       Name1   Party1      Constituency1       700
0       Name2   Party1      Constituency1       550
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is user variable and you should use `:=` not `=`

```
SELECT @i := @i + 1 AS Rank,...
```

Comment: OMG. I even used that annotation before(but then the numbers were all messed up, cause I used different function back then), but yeah, this did the trick. Thanks!